# get_bounds() returns [[None, None], [None, None]]

Tags: python-3.x, folium

With the following code, I'd expect to get the lat/long pairs of the corners of the visible map:

```
import folium

testmap = folium.Map(location=[-23.52, 115.5]
                  , zoom_start=7
                  , prefer_canvas=True
                  )

testmap.get_bounds()
```

Instead I get:

```
[[None, None], [None, None]]
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  I'm using Folium from the master branch, if that helps figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the problem too, I don't have a solution, but I know what's happening when looking at the implementation of the `get_bounds()` function.

```
def get_bounds(self):
    """Computes the bounds of the object and all it's children
    in the form [[lat_min, lon_min], [lat_max, lon_max]].
    """
    bounds = self._get_self_bounds()

    for child in self._children.values():
        child_bounds = child.get_bounds()

def _get_self_bounds(self):
    """Computes the bounds of the object itself (not including it's children)
    in the form [[lat_min, lon_min], [lat_max, lon_max]]
    """
    return [[None, None], [None, None]]
```

So, first the bound of the map itself are calculated (which returns the None values), and afterwards the children's bounds are calculated. Since in your example, there are no children, the `get_bounds()` function returns `[[None, None], [None, None]]`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/ocefpaf/815b267199a1c1d4ac43f37cf8b8d4a8

This gives you an example of how to correctly use get_bounds

Comment: Thanks for this.  From the notebook, I see that `color_line.get_bounds` gives the bounds of `color_line` but I don't understand why `m.get_bounds` also returns the same bounds.  From the [docs] (https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html), I'd expect `m.get_bounds` to give the min and max lat long of the 4 corners of the displayed map, which is the behaviour I'm looking for.